# Running a Selenium WebDriver test with a running instance aof Firefox

Tags: selenium, webdriver

i have been using the Selenium IDE for some time and now i wanted to give the WebDriver a try.
I like that its more programming than scripting and that i can use classes methods and so on.
Theres one thing, that is more convinient with the IDE.
it runs in the open window/instance of Firefox.

it is really annoing, that whenever i start the tests i have to wait till a new firefox window opens.

Does someone know if there is a way to use an open window?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not a supported feature. There is an [outstanding issue](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18) in the tracker for it though. You may wish to try an unofficial patch someone made for the Firefox and InternetExplorer drivers [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18#c39).